# Store Information Into 2 different arrays

Tags: java, arrays

**Information to be stored into the arrays:** You will store the customer ID number, first name, last name, address, cell phone 
number, and age in a two-dim String array.
You will store the customer ID number, loan amount, and loan interest rate (as a #.# 
number), and desired monthly payment amount in a two-dim double array.

**Notice that the idea here is that these two arrays “sync” up.**

The first customer in 
the information array corresponds to the first customer in the loan info array

I’m just clueless how I’m supposed to have these two different arrays match up to one another, if somebody could help me start this that would be a huge help!

Answer (score 0):

A 2D array is like a table.

```
[[1,2,3],
 [4,5,6]]
```

You can access data from this "table" using a row and column index.
Here is an example: https://www.journaldev.com/747/two-dimensional-array-java
In the below example the 0 equals the row index and the 1 equals the column index.

```
    arrMulti[0][1] = value;
```

Stacking arrays on top of each other makes a table.
So, like a table in Excel, if the first column has the customer number, you can associate the rows together.

The "table" might look like

```
[["cust num: 123", "Bob", "Jones", "etc"],
 ["cust num: 123", "123,000","3.5%","etc"]]
```

Imagine that with various rows. Two rows will match with the same customer number. Just find those two rows by iterating over the column.

Comment: Okay going off of that this is how my arrays will be made -  double [][] amortDB = new double[1000][];
        String [][] nameTable = new String[1000][2];                   I’m also allowing the user to enter in whatever they wish for each data field in the instructions (so using scanner in) ... how would I populate each position by using whatever they enter in while both arrays still match up with their customerID at the same position

Comment: good question. If the customer is allowed to enter any value into any field, perhaps a check can be done to the validate the entry. Something unique needs to be able to identify the customer number, if it is not the first entry. I think 2D arrays (and tables in general) are designed so that the order matters -- like giving a column a header.